# How to create a model from the values entered by the user?

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my model:

```dart
class Foo {
  final String name;
  final String emailId;
  Foo(this.name, this.emailId);

  factory Foo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Foo(
      json['name'] as String,
      json['email_id'] as String,
    );
  }
}
```

I want to create its object by letting user enter text in the TextField, for that I decided to use `Map`.

```dart
Map<String, dynamic> map = {};
```

My first text field:

```dart
TextFormField(
  onSaved: (s) => map['name'] = s,
)
```

and second:

```dart
TextFormField(
  onSaved: (s) => map['email_id'] = s,
)
```

I'm creating an instance using:

```dart
final foo = Foo.fromJson(map);
```

Is there any better way of creating an object without modifying my model class (`final` fields as well as non-nullable fields) except for creating various fields to store the value and then calling `Foo()` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

There is many ways to solve this, my recommendation is first to load the data, and then modify anything in the ui without touching the class.

First define your data:

```
  // Example fetch fooFromJson(String)
  final Foo foo = Foo(name: 'name', email: 'stack@overflow.com');

  // Text controllers
  late final TextEditingController _controllerName;
  late final TextEditingController _controllerEmail;

  // Form key
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
```

Define your @initState method:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    _controllerName = TextEditingController(text: foo.name);
    _controllerEmail = TextEditingController(text: foo.email);
    super.initState();
  }
```

This way, the data will fetch from the backend just one time, and will show data to the UI without touching the class.

Then in your body widget:

```
return Form(
      key: formKey,
      child: ListView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(100),
        shrinkWrap: true,
        children: [
          TextFormField(
            controller: _controllerName,
            //validator: myValidator,
          ),
          TextFormField(
            controller: _controllerEmail,
            //validator: myValidator,
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 20),
          ElevatedButton(child: const Text('Save'), onPressed: _onSaved),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

When you click save button, set the data to your class again (if you don't want to put the data again to the class **go to the end of the answer**):

```
_onSaved() {
    if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      foo.name = _controllerName.text;
      foo.email = _controllerEmail.text;
    }
  }
```

Result:

[image]

---

On the other hand, Form is use to validate data, for example you want "Text should be 10 characters maximum":

```
TextFormField(
            controller: _controllerName,
            validator: _nameValidator,
            autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
          )
```

And the function:

```
String? _nameValidator(String? text) {
    return text!.length < 10 ? 'Name should have 10 characters at least' : null;
  }
```

Result when you click save:

[image]

The data will not be saved until **validation** is correct.

---

Also if you want to fetch data from the internet or database, I recommend to improve your data class, for example you have the following Json:

```
{
    "name" :"",
    "email" : ""
}
```

The class should be:

```
import 'dart:convert';

Foo fooFromJson(String str) => Foo.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String fooToJson(Foo data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Foo {
    Foo({
        this.name,
        this.email,
    });

    String name;
    String email;

    factory Foo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Foo(
        name: json["name"],
        email: json["email"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "name": name,
        "email": email,
    };
}
```

So you can POST foo.toJson() to whatever API you have.

This is a good tool that can help you with that https://app.quicktype.io/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I didn't want to use `TextEditingController` as I have over 30 fields and creating these many controller and then disposing them is an overhead.